# DotNetNuke Nav menu not showing unless I'm loggged in?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Am working with a DotNetNuke(DNN) site and for some reason, the DNN:NAV control only displays the menu when I am logged in.

The menu is part of the template file itself, which in this case is 'index.ascx'

Any way for me to troubleshoot the visibility of the menu? Why wouldn't it be showing up? Everything else on the page is.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: When you say, "menu is part of the template file itself", do you mean the skin file? Can you include the chunk of code where you're doing the include?

Comment: Do you have any non-admin pages that have the include in menu box checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I might check is that your pages are visible by users who are not logged in - if there are no pages avaliable to all users this might happen.